# Mysql2::Error: Unknown column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I work on rails 3.2.18 and mysql 5.6.20. I created migration which create new table and It looks like this:

```
class CreateRequest < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :requests, id: false do |t|
      t.string    :id,                  null: false
      t.integer   :lesson_id,           null: false
      t.integer   :user_id,             null: false
      t.boolean   :approved,            null: false, default: false
    end

    add_index :requests, :id, unique: true
  end
end
```

I decided that I will use uuid as primary key. New record in DB I create like following:

```
def create_request(lesson)
request = Request.new.tap do |req|
  req.id = SecureRandom.uuid
  req.lesson_id = lesson.id
  req.user_id = @user.id
end
request.save
end
```

So we have Request model and It is related to two other tables Lesson (one-to-one) ans User (one-to-many). No I will show you all models.

```
class PublicizeRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name  = "requests"
  self.primary_key = "id"

  has_one     :lesson
  belongs_to  :user

end

class Lesson < ActiveRecord::Base
  (...)
  belongs_to :publicize_request
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  (...)
  has_many :publicize_requests
end
```

Now I can describe main problem. If I get request from DB and I want to get user data I can do this simple:

```
@request.user
```

But If I want get lesson in the same way I get following error:

```
 Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'lessons.request_id' in 'where clause': SELECT  `lessons`.* FROM `lessons`  WHERE `lessons`.`archived` = 0 AND `lessons`.`request_id` = 'd0da41df-a9be-4575-ada0-538abe1f54a3' LIMIT 1
```

I am newbie in rails and I don't know how to deal with this. Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your migration and relationship definition are not matching.  The rule is that whichever table you have foreign key in, you define `belongs_to` relationship on that table's model.

You have defined `lesson_id` column in `requests` table, which means that `Request` model should have `belongs_to :lesson`.

```
class PublicizeRequest < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  belongs_to  :lesson
  ...
end
```

The reason you are getting the error is because you have `has_one :lesson` in `Request` model which would imply that you have `belongs_to :request` in your `Lesson` model if you have defined it, but you do not have `request_id` column in your `lessons` table.